# Error: is not sibling of same relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

help me please i'm getting this error consequently  . layout break even application stopped.is not run. i am new to this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        >
        <!-- recipients -->
        <TextView 
            android:id = "@+id/main_row_recepient_area"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_row_message_area"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/main_row_extra_recepient_area"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/main_row_recepient_area"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/main_row_recepient_area"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:textColor="@color/listing_text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            >
        </TextView>

        <!-- Date and Time -->    
        <TextView 
            android:id = "@+id/main_row_date_area"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "205dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            >
        </TextView>

        <!-- repeat icon -->
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/repeat_icon"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/main_row_date_area"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/repeat_icon_big"/>

        <!-- message -->    
        <TextView 
            android:id = "@id/main_row_message_area"
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/listing_text"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_below="@id/main_row_date_area"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/main_row_image_area"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            >
        </TextView>

        <!-- icon -->  
        <com.vinsol.sms_scheduler.utils.LinearLayoutExtended
            android:id="@+id/container_layout"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/list_divider_holo_dark"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <com.vinsol.sms_scheduler.utils.ExtendedImageView 
            android:id = "@+id/main_row_image_area"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_width ="80dp"
            android:padding="20dp"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            >
            </com.vinsol.sms_scheduler.utils.ExtendedImageView>

        </com.vinsol.sms_scheduler.utils.LinearLayoutExtended>


    </RelativeLayout>

    >android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/main_row_image_area"  (is not sibling)

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        >
        <!-- Header -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text = "Auto Wish Sender"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            >
        </TextView>

        <!-- time in past, warning message -->    
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id = "@+id/past_time_label"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/new_date_label"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:paddingBottom="3dip"
                android:background="@color/warning_yellow"
                android:text="  Time in past, message will be sent now"
                android:textColor="@color/black" 
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/warning_sign"
                >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- footer -->    
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/footer_bg" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/new_schedule_button"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/schedule_footer_states"
                >
            </Button>

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/new_cancel_button"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cancel_footer_states"
                >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- body -->
        <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/Scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_below="@id/past_time_label"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"
            >
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/body"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:paddingRight="10dip"
                >
                <!-- contacts linear layout -->
                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    >



                    <!--<AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id = "@+id/new_numbers_text"
                        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Recipients"
                        android:minLines="2"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/new_add_from_contact_imgbutton"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                        android:background="@drawable/auto_complete_bg"
                        >
                    </AutoCompleteTextView>-->

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_wrapper"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/new_add_from_contact_imgbutton"
                        android:background="@drawable/textfield_default" >

                        <LinearLayout 
                            android:id="@+id/layouts_host"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/details_button_layout"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:minHeight="30dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            >

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/edit_text_host"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <AutoCompleteTextView 
                                    android:background="#00000000"
                                    android:id="@+id/recipients_autocomplete_text"
                                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                                    android:minWidth="1dp"
                                    android:hint="Recipients"
                                    android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>


                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@id/details_button_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                            <ImageView 
                                android:src="@drawable/vertical_divider_for_message_header"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/recipients_detail_image"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                                android:fadingEdgeLength="2dp"/>

                            <ImageView 
                                android:id="@+id/recipients_detail_image"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_more_states"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <ImageButton 
                        android:id = "@id/new_add_from_contact_imgbutton"
                        android:layout_width = "45dp"
                        android:layout_height = "45dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/choose_contact_button_states"
                        android:background="@drawable/add_from_contacts_bg_states"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        >
                    </ImageButton>      
                </RelativeLayout>

                <!-- Date and Repeat time button -->
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button 
                        android:id = "@+id/new_date_button"
                        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight = "4"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/date_time_button_states"
                    >
                    </Button>

                    <ImageButton 
                        android:id="@+id/repeat_button"
                        android:layout_width="58dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/repeat_button_states"
                        android:background="@drawable/add_from_contacts_bg_states"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Rep"/>

                </LinearLayout>


                <!-- message edit text -->
                <!-- message top layout -->
                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/message_top_layout"        
                    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/message_header_bg"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingRight="10dip"
                    >

                    <!-- template button -->
                    <ImageButton 
                        android:id = "@+id/template_imgbutton"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/template_icon_states"
                        >
                    </ImageButton>

                    <!-- vertical splitter -->
                    <ImageView 
                        android:id = "@+id/splitter1"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/template_imgbutton"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/vertical_divider_for_message_header"
                        >
                    </ImageView>    

                    <!-- voice button -->
                    <ImageButton 
                        android:id = "@+id/speech_imgbutton"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dip"
                        android:background="@drawable/voice_icon_states"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/splitter1"
                        >
                    </ImageButton>

                    <!-- vertical splitter -->
                    <ImageView 
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/speech_imgbutton"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/vertical_divider_for_message_header"
                        >
                    </ImageView>        

                    <!-- add to template button -->
                    <ImageButton 
                        android:id = "@+id/add_template_imgbutton"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/add_to_template_states"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        >
                    </ImageButton>

                    <!-- vertical splitter -->
                    <ImageView 
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/add_template_imgbutton"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/vertical_divider_for_message_header"
                        >
                    </ImageView>        
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/message_bg"
                    >
                    <!-- message edit text -->
                    <EditText
                        android:id = "@+id/new_message_space" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:hint="Type your Message here"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:capitalize="sentences"
                        android:layout_below="@id/message_top_layout"
                        android:minLines="4"
                        android:background="@drawable/message_bg"
                        >
                    </EditText>

                    <!-- char count text -->    
                    <TextView
                        android:id = "@+id/new_char_count_text"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                        android:text = "0"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/char_count_grey"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        >
                    </TextView>
                </RelativeLayout>


                <!-- smiley -->
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id = "@+id/smiley_layout"
                    android:orientation = "vertical"
                    android:layout_height= "120dp"
                    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/emoticons_bg"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <GridView 
                        android:id = "@+id/smileysGrid"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                        android:columnWidth="35dp"
                        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                        android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        >
                    </GridView>
                </LinearLayout>       
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>   
    </RelativeLayout>
```

> android:layout_below="@id/message_top_layout"(is not siblling of same    relativelayout)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're asking `new_message_space`'s position to be relative to the `RelativeLayout` `message_top_layout`, which you can't do because `new_message_space` is **within** `message_top_layout`.

Try removing it, aligning it according to its parent or making it relative to one of its siblings (a view within the same parent) such as `new_char_count_text`.

Comment: please tell me how i am new and first i getting this error. i already change 'message_top_layout' ,it should not work @Embattled Swag

Answer (score 0):

Your `main_row_image_area` is in a `LinearLayoutExtended`, so you can't reference it from another Layout. Maybe what you really want to do is place it to the left of `container_layout`?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your **build.gradle** file

```
android {
    lintOptions {
       checkReleaseBuilds false
       abortOnError false
    }
}
```